# ECB Menu "strAction" last value array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecb-menu

Created an Element in the ECB menu with dynamic items, when you try to access an item by clicking, the entire array is traversed and the last item is substituted, help the clicker to display the value of the desired item?

[image]

F12:

[image]

Code:

```
var L_DocumentLibrary_Text = "Copy items";
strDisplayText = L_DocumentLibrary_Text;
var docLib = CASubM(m,strDisplayText,"","",400);
docLib.id = "id_L_DocumentLibrary_Text";
var Const_DocLibs_Array = ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4"];
for(var i = 0; i < Const_DocLibs_Array.length; i++)
 {
  var L_Doc_Text = Const_DocLibs_Array[i];
  strDisplayText = L_Doc_Text;
  strAction = "console.log('" + strDisplayText + "');";
  strImagePath = ctx.imagesPath + "existingLocations.gif";
  menuOption = CAMOpt(docLib,strDisplayText,strAction,strImagePath);
  menuOption.id = "id_" + L_Doc_Text;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `strAction` doesn't get evaluated until the whole loop completes. So the easy way to do this would be to forget the loop and write four separate `CAMOpt` calls each with its own `strAction`.

Comment: Thank you, then this solution does not suit me, thank you.